# need to switch to a different branch not listed in git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git submodule 'library' that I want to make changes to. The submodule currently tracks my 'develop' branch. I want the submodule to track a feature branch so the changes are associated with that branch.

I've tried going into the submodule folder and doing:
`git checkout feature` and got `error: pathspec 'feature' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

When I ran `git branch -a` in the submodule folder I noticed my feature branch was not listed. I tried adding it by running `git submodule add -b feature` but that didn't work.

When I run `git status` in the submodule folder it says:

```
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'
```

How do I switch the branch my git submodule is tracking?

Comment: did you `fetch` inside your submodule?

Comment: @ian I ran `fetch' and it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add a new branch named feature you need to first add it with this command:

```
git checkout -b feature
```

Answer (score 0):

In your submodule folder inside the main project:

`git branch -avv` will show you all branches known.

if it is not there and will not show even after a fetch then check you remote.

Otherwise just `git checkout feature` should work. If ambiguous `git checkout -b feature origin/feature`